# least squares svm in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, svm, matlab

Which ls-svm toolbox can  use in matlab? Which implementation do you recommend?

Comment: If you mean 'least-squares support vector machine' I suggest you put it in your question.  If not, then put what you do mean in your question.

Comment: Thanks, i modified it. It is about least squares svm of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out both libsvm and liblinear:

- http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/
- http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/

These the are the fastest SVM solvers that I know of.

Comment: I found libsvm can compute this type:

 0 -- C-SVC
 1 -- nu-SVC
 2 -- one-class SVM
 3 -- epsilon-SVR
 4 -- nu-SVR

Can you help, which one is least square?

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure what type of SVM you're referring to, but I'm assuming you're interested in an implementation of the least squares SVM of Suykens & Vanderwalle, NIPS 99.  If that's the case, I believe neither libsvm nor liblinear do that; check out http://www.esat.kuleuven.be/sista/lssvmlab/  .

If you're interested in a normal quadratic-programming formulation of the svm with quadratic slack penalties, libsvm and liblinear should work.  Also, the newer subgradient-based solvers, such as pegasos may be useful as well but I am not sure of whether there is a good matlab library for you to use.

Comment: I mixed up the soft margin SVM and LS-SVM. I looked for soft-margin SVM, not for LS-SVM. Since then i realized, that the standard MATLAB bioinfo svmtrain function can handle both. Thanks for everybody.